# Java and Javascript Regex format for numbers after an @ sign

Tags: java, javascript, regex, parsing, text

What's the regex in Java to capture pieces of text after the @ sign in a string that's formatted like this:

```
@+300 regex returns +300

@300 regex that should returns 300

@300.00 regex that should return 300.00

123123@300.00 should not return anything

@300.00@ should not return anything

@300.00.00 should not return anything
```

Kind of like username mentions in Twitter but with decimal numbers (positive and negative).

Comment: JavaScript is very far from Java. Questions shouldn't be tagged with both.

Comment: Have you attempted to solve this problem yourself? StackOverflow questions should demonstrate a minimal understanding of the question be asked, including attempted solutions.

Comment: @Dukeling 
I'd really appreciate those who can answer both Javascript and Java answers for this question. 
Yes I've done it in Java, but I'm stuck with this regex and have a hard time expanding it further: `(?:\\s|\\A)[@]+([0-9-_]+)`

Comment: what about `@300.000` or `@300.` ?

Comment: `@300.000` = is ok, but for `@300.` it shouldn't return anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
String myString = "@123.45";
String returned = null;

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^@([+-]?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)$");
Matcher m = p.matcher(myString);

if(m.find()) {
    returned = m.group(1);
}
```

Comment: `(?:\\+)?` can be simplified to `\\+?` but should be changed to `[+-]?` to include negative numbers as well. And you should use `matches`, not `find` (for semantic correctness and possibly performance, although it won't change the output given that you use `^` and `$`). And `1.` and `.1` are often considered valid formats for decimal numbers, but whether these are wanted is anyone's guess.

Comment: @Dukeling right, sorry, In Australia it's already 11,00 pm and almost all my neurons are asleep... fixing

Comment: Again I was doing asumptions not specified by OP. Fixed again

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@([+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

Then consider the first group out of the match.

Answer (score -1):

Try this for Java and let me know if it helps -

```
    String toCheck = "@300.20";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^@([+-]?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)$");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(toCheck);

    if (m.matches()){
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    } else {
        System.out.println("Oops! didn't match");
    }
```

And for Javascript this might help-

```
   var toCheck= "@300.20";
   var regex = /^@([+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)$/;
   var matches = regex.exec(toCheck);
   var reqd = matches[1];
```

Comment: @Ace Subido, do you think my answer is useful to you in anyways?
It even won't match 300. the way you want. Thanks!

Comment: It won't match `@1` and doesn't include an optional `+` or `-` sign, other than that it's very similar to [a somewhat older answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17898032/1711796). (I didn't downvote)

Comment: @Dukeling: Ahh!!! I see - thanks again. Does it look OK now? My answer also includes Javascript regex and a few of the things are differently done. So, it's not similar.

Comment: `@1.` will still match. See [the other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17898032/1711796) for a way to avoid this.

Comment: @Dukeling- Yeah! more or less it became like what Morgano did. 
I have some updates for Javascript part though. So, should I keep this answer? Or Delete?